# Is possible to support multiple inheritance through virtual?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

I know that Java does not have any ability to support Multiple Inheritance. For an example, class C inherits all the properties from class A and class B then the compiler gets confused which method should be called which is defined in A and B. So, C++ supports multiple Inheritance and Java does not support.

I know that by using Interface can achieve this Multiple Inheritance in Java.

My doubt is, whats that Diamond problem and how could be solved in Java?

For an example, consider multiple classes such as A, B, C, D. Class B and Class C inherits the  properties from Class A and class D inherits the properties from both class B and Class C. This is called as "Diamond problem".

How can we solve this Diamond problem in Java and when does this Diamond problem may occur exactly in coding?

I also referred that in C++ by using Virtual can achieve this Multiple Inheritance concept. And, Java is built and designed for simplicity !

What is that actual meaning of Virtual in C++ and how could be used in Java? Is it possible to achieve multiple Inheritance through Virtual?

I am Java Beginner and very sorry for this kinda question. But, I believe that can learn from my mistakes!

Comment: It is not true that you can use interfaces to achieve multiple inheritance.  You can never inherit an implementation from two unrelated other classes.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, you can never get the C++ - style multiple inheritance by extending two classes. All you can do is implement multiple interfaces. There is no 'diamond' situation in Java =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of multiple inheritance in Java.  Implementing multiple interfaces is possible, but this is *not* multiple inheritance.

Because there's no multiple inheritance, the "diamond problem" that arises in languages that *do* have multiple inheritance does not arise in Java.  So there is no `virtual` keyword in Java - there's no need for it.

The designers of Java decided that the number of cases in which multiple inheritance is actually useful is so small that it wasn't worth including in the language.  In approximately 15 years of programming Java, I have only *once* encountered a business problem in which C++-style multiple inheritance would have been useful.  So I'm happy to say they were right.

Comment: Yeah, Is there any other reasons behind that there is no need of Virtual in Java and if its so instead of 'virtual' how we are achieving and why dont we need virtual in Java? I need to understand the concept of Virtual. And, what would we use to call if class implements multiple Interfaces so is it not supposed to be a multiple Inheritance?? Please kindly forgive If I am wrong in anything. As a Java beginner just learning from you!

Comment: OK, but "virtual" is a C++ concept, not a Java concept.  Java simply doesn't have multiple inheritance.  Asking how to use "virtual" is like asking how to clean the carburettor on a bicycle.

Comment: I'm happy to clarify further if needed, Meena.  I always struggled with the exact meaning of "virtual", when I was programming C++.

Comment: Yeah, definitely I may get doubts in a future. You are experienced than me so definitely I can ask you.. Where should I ask my doubts? In this same Question? @David Wallace

Comment: If they relate directly to this question, sure, add a comment to this question.  Make sure you ping me if you want my attention - just by putting @ in front of my name.  If it's not related to this question, post a new question - I might see it, and if I don't someone equally knowledgeable is sure to.  And don't be shy because you think of yourself as a beginner.  Everyone was a beginner once.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much for your positive words and thanks a lot to stackoverflow site too, because of this site only I am really getting much clear in some concepts..

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple 'inheritance', you need to implement multiple `interfaces`. Each interface declares abstract methods that the implementing class needs to provide definition for.

```
public class MyClass implements interface1, interface2, interface3{
  // provide a definition to the abstract methods of interface
}
```

The 'diamond' problem in C++ is when a class inherits from two classes , both of whom have methods from a common grand parent. In Java, there is no diamond problem because you can **never** extend two classes; just one class and many interfaces.

You are combining far too many questions. I recommend that you split your post into separate questions.